# Issue in Importing a Virtual Disk in gcloud ( Centos 6.7)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I was trying to import a Virtual Disk in `gcloud` from my local Premise Openstack Setup .But I am not able to successfully launch VM instance for Centos 6.7 in gcloud.

I tried various options to run Custom Image on gcp :

```
Centos 6.7

Raw image 20 GB
vmdk 8 GB image  
qcow2 image  7.3 GB
Openstack compatible CentOS 6.x image  1.2 GB ( Downloaded from Internet)
```

### Steps Followed

- First we have created a Bucket in our project to upload custom images( above 4 Images) .
- Installed/Configured  Google Cloud SDK  .
  Used following command to create image from our custom images  ( Each Image creation takes at least 2 Hours)
  gcloud compute images import my-imported-image --source-file gs://your_gcs_bucket/your_server.vmdk --os centos-9
- Launched VM using above custom image, gcp shows Instance Running but not able to ssh the VM.
  To debug Step 4 , Enabled the serial port on VM , various errors were coming on serial console , it seems VM not boot up properly.
  gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]  --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
- Tried below option for Making an image bootable, it also did not worked.
  `Gcloud compute images import [IMAGE_NAME] --source-image [SOURCE_IMAGE] --os [OS]`
- GCP showing instance running but on serial console we can see some error.

Note:

- On GCP help links, GCP strongly recommended to use pre_check tool on VM , but we are getting following error ( we are running binary with root user but still getting errors)

> [root@host]# ./import_precheck
>
> FATAL: 2018/05/25 18:50:09.042337 main.go:54: must be run as root
>
> FATAL: 2018/05/25 18:50:09.042337 main.go:54: must be run as root

- We also tried to browse the code for this binary (import_precheck) , but not able to download it due to link unavailable (Used the link given by GCP).

Can someone please help me in Launching a Centos 6.7 Image on gcloud.

Comment: You explained that you are launching VM instance for CentOS 6.7 in gcloud command. However I've found 'CentOS-9' in your above mentioned command which is not supported and publish yet. I recommend you to take a look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#precheck) to check compatibility.

Comment: I ran it on Debian 9, supported, and got the same result :-(